# Mongodb double group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have 2 table, `competitions` and `subscription`

structure Table `competition`

```
_id | name | price
1  | A    | 5000
2  | B    | 2500
```

structure Table `subscription`

```
_id | competition | created_at
1  | 1           | November 26, 2019, 10:20 AM
2  | 1           | November 26, 2019, 10:22 AM
3  | 2           | November 26, 2019, 10:23 AM
```

My query

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "competition",
      "localField": "competition",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "comp_detail"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$comp_detail"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "month": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          "date": "$created_at"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$month",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Result

```
_id        | count
2019-11-26 | 20
2019-11-27 | 30
```

My expectation result:

```
_id        | count | 5000 | 2500
2019-11-26 | 20    | 15   | 5
2019-11-27 | 30    | 3    | 27
```

How to do that? Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

That `$project` stage is removing all of fields from the document, so the following stages only get `month` and `_id`, so the first change will be to use `$addFields` instead.

```
 {
    "$addFields": {
      "month": {

   ...
```

Group by the inner fields first:

```
{$group: { 
    _id:{
         month: "$month",
         price: "$comp_detail.price"
    },
    count: {$sum: 1}
}}
```

The group by the outer field and add up the counts, creating an array:

```
{$group:{
  _id: "$_id.month",
  count: {$sum: "$count"},
  values: {$push:{ k:{$toString:"$_id.price"}, v: "$count"}}}
}}
```

use `$arrayToObject` to assemble the array:

```
{$addFields: {
   values: {$arrayToObject: "$values"}
}}
```

This will leave you with a values object containing the price-count mapping for the month.